# Google Analytics 4 . get report of Average Load Time of specific page over a period of time

Tags: google-analytics

I want to make a report, in which I can get the average load time of specific page. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Do you need help with Google Tag Manager, Reports in Analytics or with custom definitions?

Comment: @Trebor I need help with google tag manager to achieve the described report.

Comment: Take a look at this custom script.  https://www.analyticsmania.com/google-tag-manager-recipes/page-load-time/